# Getting Notice (8): Undefined property error in CakePHP 1.2.5

Tags: php, cakephp

I have no idea why I should get the above error. Also, in the same line, I'm getting the dreadful 
`Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on a non-object` error.

I have a controller `home_loan_installment_repayment_controller.php`, which has an `index` and `view` method.

```
class HomeLoanInstallmentRepaymentController extends AppController {

    function index() {
        //some work done here
    }

    function view() {
        //some work done here
    }
}
```

In the view page `index.ctp` of this controller, I'm calling another controller `home_loan_installment_repayment_details_controller.php`, which also has index() and view() methods. Something like this:

```
<td class="actions">
     <?php echo $html->link(__('View', true), array('action' => 'view', 'branch_id' => $branch_id, 'date' => $info[$i]['HomeLoanInstallmentRepayments']['REPAYMENT_DATE'])); ?>
      <a href="/sdb/HomeLoanInstallmentRepayment/edit/2014-11-25/branch_id:18">Edit</a>
      <a onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete # 2014-11-25?');" href="/sdb/HomeLoanInstallmentRepayment/delete/2014-11-25/branch_id:18">Delete</a>
      <!--The following link will navigate to a different controller-->
      <a href="/sdf-mis/HomeLoanInstallmentRepaymentDetails/index/branch_id:18">Installment Details</a>
</td>
```

In my `home_loan_installment_repayment_details_controller.php` controller, the following thing is done:

```
class HomeLoanInstallmentRepaymentDetailsController extends AppController {

        function index() {
            //In the following line, I'm getting the two errors
             $info = $this->HomeLoanInstallmentRepaymentDetails->query("SOME SQL QUERY");
             echo "<pre>";
             print_r($info);
             die();
        }

        function view() {
            //some work done here
        }
    }
```

After I $print_r($info), I get the errors:

```
Notice (8): Undefined property: HomeLoanInstallmentRepaymentDetailsController::$HomeLoanInstallmentRepaymentDetails [APP\controllers\home_loan_installment_repayment_details_controller.php, line 5

Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on a non-object in C:\wamp\www\sdb\app\controllers\home_loan_installment_repayment_details_controller.php on line 5
```

Note that I don't have any models for the above two controllers and I bypassed using models.

Comment: _"In the past few posts of mine, I've noticed that I've received very few and very late answers. So I'd expect a couple of quicker responses and answers"_ - I think you were very lucky not to receive an avalanche of downvotes for that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling the method with the controller's instance.You must have a model to do operation on the data.`query()` is a method of model so define the model. Try with the model name -

```
$info = $this-><your model name>->query("SOME SQL QUERY");
```

If you model is - `HomeLoanInstallmentRepaymentDetail` then try -

```
$info = $this->HomeLoanInstallmentRepaymentDetail->query("SOME SQL QUERY");
```

Or if you dont want to define the model then -

```
ClassRegistry::init('AppModel')->query('Your query');
```

Comment: *Note that I don't have any models for the above two controllers and I bypassed using models.* I'd suggest you to read my entire question thoroughly before answering.

Comment: Well this is very very confusing. For the first controller, I don't have any model either, still I used the query() method there and it's working fine. If I can work with the query() method without model for my first controller, why won't it work for the second?

Comment: My problem is solved by just renaming the Property to `HomeLoanInstallmentRepaymentDetail` instead of creating a single Model. I didn't even use the `ClassRegistry::init('AppModel')->query('Query');` function, nor did I use `var $uses = array()`. Then how come I'm still being able to use the controller properly?

Comment: It is the cake who is doing all this.`HomeLoanInstallmentRepaymentDetail` is supposed to be your model name.

Comment: I told you, I don't have any model at all, let alone it be`HomeLoanInstallmentRepaymentDetail`. I didn't even follow the cake standards of writing `$var uses = array();` in order to use the controller without any model. Nor did I write your above mentioned `ClassRegistry::init('AppModel')` method. Yet I'm able to write the `$this->HomeLoanInstallmentRepaymentDetail-query()` perfectly and I can retrieve data perfectly. Very mysterious indeed. Is it something to do with my CakePHP version or PHP version? My Cake version is 1.2.5, PHP version is 5.2.11.

Comment: Its not necessary.. Cake assumes there is a model with that name and the table also though it is not defined..

Comment: Abundantly clear sire. I was confused because the documentations tell otherwise : *If you do not wish to use a Model in your controller, set var $uses = array(). This will allow you to use a controller without a need for a corresponding Model file.* Check: http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/The-Manual/Developing-with-CakePHP/Controllers.html